# Blender can't find a GPU capable of path tracing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

A few months ago, I was able to see my GPU under the CUDA and OpenCL tabs in user preferences, but after I factory reset my laptop and reinstalled blender 2.80, the option to use my GPU for rendering no longer exists and I get a message saying "No compatible GPUs found for path tracing. Cycles will render on the CPU".

I have a GTX 1060, and all drivers appear to be up to date.

Comment: re install the drivers for the GPU

Comment: @susu I just did a clean reinstallation and restarted my computer, and unfortunately nothing has changed in Blender.

Comment: use blender 2.83, the latest version.